# AWS Batch Logs to splunk

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, splunk, aws-batch

I am using AWS Batch Service for my job. i want to send the logs generated from AWS Batch directly to Splunk instead of sending that to cloud-watch. How can i configure log-driver in AWS Batch to achieve this?

-ND

Answer (score 0):

Splunk provides 3 methods to forward logs from a host server to the cloud server.

- Splunk Forwarder (agent)
- Http Event Collector (HEC)
- Splunk logging driver for Docker

But, Splunk HTTP Event Collector (HEC) is the easy and efficient way to send data to Splunk Enterprise and Splunk Cloud in your scenario. You can send logs through Http request using HEC. This can be defined in your AWS batch job definition. [Tutorial](http://dev.splunk.com/view/event-collector/SP-CAAAFBZ).

Other than that, you can use Splunk Docker logging driver, since AWS batch job will be spawn on an ECS container. For this method, you should define a custom AMI(for compute environment) which configured the docker daemon to send all the container logs to particular Splunk server.

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Batch logs can be sent to Cloudwatch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/features/#Integrated_monitoring_and_logging) and using [Splunk Add on for AWS](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1876/#/overview) or using one of the AWS LAMBDA functions (HTTP Event Collector) can be onboarded into Splunk.
[image: Lambda Blue Print (splunk-cloudwatch-logs-processor)]